# tool generated from setuptool needs alias name

Tags: python, compatibility, setuptools

I have a tool that generates whl setup package from setuptool. It's old name is "a_tool". It's setup code is below:

```
name="a_tool",
version=__version__,
packages=find_packages(
    exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
```

Now I need to change the name of the tool to "b_tool", but also I need to have compatibility to older codes with has imports like this:

```
from a_tool import a_module
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to so something similar and ended up doing what is described in a similar [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559817/how-do-i-alias-a-python-module-at-packaging-time).

Basically, make another top-level module and have it point to the existing module.

Comment: Cool, this would probably work for me. Have you ever run into any corner cases that this solution does not work?

Comment: @Johnzy it works but it can be a headache to support two essentially different APIs in the same project. Well defined API contracts with type hints and good tests can help to alleviate the pain. As with any API, as long as you do not remove data from the contract, change a type or require additional data for your API you should be ok. Adding new data to