# Python setuptools: is it mandatory that the package name is the folder name?

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, packaging

For a specific project, I don't want to store my Python package into a folder with a long name. Using setuptools, and installing in developer mode, I wish I could *name my package as I want* for the imports, but *in a folder with another name*:

```
# Project structure
my-exploratory-analysis
    - 2021-04-28_analyse-XY.md
    - 2021-04-29_Z-versus-XY.md
    - other .py, .ipynb, .sh files
    - setup.py  # to install the "tools" as a package
    - tools/
        - __init__.py
        - common_tools.py
        - XY_tools.py
        - _tests/
```

From a python analysis:

```py
# wanted import name:
from myexploratory_analysis.common_tools import myregression
```

*Is it mandatory that the folder name becomes the package name?* I can't find a workaround.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559817/how-do-i-alias-a-python-module-at-packaging-time) suggests that this is not possible.

Installing something named "tools" system-wide does not seem specific enough, and having a "myexploratory_analysis" nested folder is redundant and cumbersome.

Comment: Just give your package a meaningful name instead of "tools". A _folder with another name_ will break the imports either while developing or after installing.